# New subdomain sending issues through Marketing Cloud Shared IP

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, ip, ip-warming

Provisioned a new Subdomain for email sending in Marketing Cloud using the Shared IP option. Having issues with emails being flagged as an external sender for the client's outlook with the links not working (blocked). The sends are working fine on gmail and other platforms with the links working as well.

What is the potential solution? Shouldn't this not be an issue since we are using Marketing Cloud's shared IP's which should bypass the need for an IP warming and since our sends are very limited and will never reach the threshold needed for a dedicated IP.

Any suggestions/solutions appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, that using a shared IP address doesn't require IP warmup, but - you still have not mentioned your volumes, which makes it difficult to help you. Using shared IP makes you rely on other senders using the same, and their sending behaviour. Resolving sender issues on shared IP can be difficult/impossible, but you should still try and raise a support case with Salesforce or Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:
you are talking about the client's own infrastructure, as in your client is "company" and you are seeing issues on mails sent from SFMC to inboxes "someone@company.com", i.e. internal recipients.

It's a typical pattern in any email tool implementation that after switching vendors, mails to internal recipients are caught by the client's IT infrastructure - spam policies etc.
To them the new emails look like any other advertiser, and as a consequence, they enforce their respective measures. They might just not allow list-based sending, advertising in general etc. - which is a 100% legitimate interest for an IT department. And there also is no way for you to "mask" that you are doing exactly these things. IP and sender domain don't matter here at first (after all, how would the client's IT department know about your IP and domain?), but they can be used to identify your sendouts in the future:

So the first idea would be to get in touch internally with the client's IT, highlighting which domain and IP you are sending from to allow an exception from their generic policies.

Comment: this was the exact problem, spot on.